# select max using group by column from another table

Tags: sql, join, group-by, grouping, max

Given the following tables:

```
tableA(v1,v2)
tableB(v3,v4)
tableC(v5,v6)
```

I want to write a query like the following one:

```
SELECT MAX(v1)
FROM tableA
WHERE v2 IN (SELECT v3
             FROM tableB
             WHERE v4 IN (SELECT v5
                          FROM tableC
                         )
             )
GROUP BY v6
```

Is something like this possible only by using IN?? I know how to write it by using JOINs between my three tables but I don't want to use JOINs.

Comment: Just out of interest, why don't you want to use joins?

Comment: Not wanting to use joins is like not wanting to use `where`, or `order by`... they are fundamental to Sql.

Comment: In dbms I am working with, `IN` is much faster than using `JOIN` as I want to compare only one value from one table with one value from  the other one... So I just wandering if something like the above one could be done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do this without using `JOIN` (at least in MS-SQL).

> Expressions in the GROUP BY clause can contain columns of the tables, derived tables or views in the FROM clause. The columns are not required to appear in the SELECT clause  list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx